# Using systemd-run To Limit I/O on cPanel for Grep Command

Tags: systemd, grep, resource-management, utilization

When I run the `grep` command on Linux on my cPanel-based shared hosting account, I hit an I/O resource limit, it says on the cPanel. I tried to research how to limit resources on a command that I run and came across `systemd-run`. I don't know if that's the right command to use or not for a one-off grep request. If it isn't, please let me know what command I can use in front of the `grep` command to limit I/O. If it is, what switches do I use to limit the I/O allocation for the `grep` command so that it doesn't hit the I/O resource limit on my cPanel shared hosting account?

Comment: Or maybe I should use the `nice` command? I tried `nice -19 grep -iR 'testnicecommand' mydir`, as well as tried numbers 10 and 5 and that didn't seem to help on the I/O resource limit issue.

Comment: You can use `ionice`.